# jsdoc - default property value inside param object

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

For the following jsdoc @param object, how do I assign a default value to `name`?

```
/** 
    @param inbound {{
        email: string,
        name: string,
        req: Req
    }}
*/
```

I have tried

```
/** 
    @param inbound {{
        email: string,
        name: [string=""],
        req: Req
    }}
*/
```

but that just turns it into an array `[string, ""]`.

I'm also preferring this `@param` style over `@typedef` as vscode shows me the properties of the object using `@param`, while it doesn't show it for `@typedef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional parameters are documented in the document [Types in the Closure Type System](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System#optional)
 on the [Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki) wiki.

In short, the default value should be provided using JS.

```
/**
 * Some class, initialized with an optional value.
 * @param {!Object=} opt_value Some value (optional).
 * @constructor
 */
function MyClass(opt_value) {
  /**
   * Some value.
   * @private {!Object|undefined}
   */
  this.myValue_ = opt_value || 'foo';
}
```

However, your question specifically refers to a default property within a document. To my knowledged "deep defaulting" is not thing in vanilla JS, not in the method signature anyhow, so it's unlikely you will find a pure JSDocs way to accomplish this.

Just write a good description and implement in JS. You could create a very simple class with this default property being returned by a getter/setter.